# A geometric understanding of Kaluza-Klein theory?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, kaluza-klein

Here's how I understand the Einstein field equations: in the presence of pure mass (no pressure), the eigen-basis of the Ricci tensor is the same as the particle's rest frame, and all 4 components are equal and positive (ie. $R_{\mu\nu}$ is a multiple of the identity matrix here).  Hence the Ricci curvature along any direction of spacetime is positive.  Applying this to the time direction explains gravitational attraction.  But note that also implies the *sectional* curvatures are all positive as well -- *all* geodesics are converging in this vicinity.

Now the original KK theory is just 5D GR, so the above statements should all still hold.  The main difference is that the manifold is cylindrical along the 5th dimension, and since this implies the metric is the same on all 4D cross-sections, particles are no longer localized to worldlines but rather worldsheets.

So we have a worldsheet on which the timelike Ricci eigenvector follows the particle's "5-velocity" $u$.  Local geodesics are still the paths of test particles, but if the source particle has charge, ie. its $u^5$ is nonzero, then some test particles will be repelled by it: those that also have a $u^5$ of the same sign.  So we have diverging geodesics, and hence negative sectional curvature, in the plane formed by those two 5-velocities.  Strictly speaking, they only need to diverge in the 4D slice, but I don't see how they could do so without also diverging in 5D.  I mean, if they converge then they might even intersect again, which cannot be hidden by restricting to 4D.

In which case, the statement of all-positive sectional curvature is violated.  So in short, I just don't get how a purely attractive interaction can ever give rise to a repulsive one, even when restricted to a lower-dimensional cross-section.  I can superficially follow the mathematical derivation, but that doesn't really help me see what's truly going on.  Thoughts, anyone?